# What is the Time and space Complexity of maxOccuringDigit() function?

Tags: java, arrays, function, time-complexity, big-o

```
static int maxOccuringDigit(int n) {
    int tempNum = n;
    if (tempNum < 0)
        tempNum = -tempNum;

    int[] count = new int[10];

    while (tempNum != 0) {
        int rem = tempNum % 10;
        count[rem] = count[rem] + 1;
        tempNum = tempNum / 10;
    }

    int maxCount = count[0];
    int digit = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < count.length; i++) {
        if (count[i] > maxCount) {
            maxCount = count[i];
            digit = i;
        } else if (count[i] == maxCount)
            digit = -1;
    }
    return digit;
}
```

The task is to find which digit occurs maximum times. I need help in analyzing the time complexity of this function. I think it should be **O(k) where k is the total digits in given number n.**
Mainly I am curious about the time complexity of **for loop used here**. As it will always loop for 10 times, can we consider it as constant time operation?

So **total O(k + 10) ~ O(k) time**. Is that correct?

Also for space complexity it is using 10 extra spaces of array only, so what will be its space complexity too?

Comment: O(k + 10) is *exactly* equal to O(k).

Answer (score 1):

The while loop will run `log10(N)` times. Yes, the for loop is run once for N and the fact that it runs 10 times is negligible, i.e. C = 10.

So the runtime complexity of your method is `log10(N) + C` and as C is negligible, `log10(N)` is its runtime complexity.

Space complexity is `O(1)`.

Comment: How can we conclude it will be log10(N) time. Can you explain why it is logN?

Comment: @NirmalSilwal check my answer. N is the number itself, not the digit count. Runtime complexity should be notated based on the input itself, not the count of digits

Comment: okay I agree to that point. Can you also explain how logN is picked here?

Comment: @NirmalSilwal Your while loop will run as many times as the number of digits in N in base 10. Read here for more info: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/335063
If N is 1000000 (one million), then your loop will run 7 times which is its digit count. 7 = log10(1000000) + 1.

Answer (score 1):

The first loop depends on the number of digits, `k`, and is `O(k)`. The second loop depends on the number of elements in the `count` array, which is 10. Since that's a constant, it runs in `O(1)`. The overall time complexity is therefore `O(k)`.

Space complexity is `O(1)` for the same reason as why the time complexity for the second loop is `O(1)`.

Comment: Now I am wondering the time complexity, though I also think it should be O(k), @Juvanis answer says its O(log10N)?

Comment: I don't think it is O(log N) (or O(log K) for that matter). Since you're basically just reducing the length of tempNum by 1 each loop.

Comment: Exactly, when we are reducing the size by half every time, we can consider it be O(logN), here no such elimination of steps are there.

Comment: @NirmalSilwal check my answer. N is the number itself, not the digit count. Runtime complexity should be notated based on the input itself, not the count of digits.